# why ostringstream could not work well in multithreading environment

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, stl, pthreads

Maybe something is weird. When I use STL ostringstream class in my multithreading environment I found that the execution time of each thread increased linearly as the thread number increased. I don't know why this happened. I try to check the ostringstream source code but could not find any synchronization code. Are there some synchronization place in ostringsstream? I replace ostringsstream with snprintf and the preformance increase largely. My OS is RHEL5.4 64BIT and my server has two xeon 5620 cpu on it.

The following is the running result
I use 1 and 8 thread separately with 1000000 loops. the left column is threadid and the right is 
running time. So it's apparant the per thread running time increase as the thread number increase.

```
[host]$./multi_thread  1 1000000
1115760960:0.240113
[host]$./multi_thread  8 1000000
1105004864:8.17012
1115494720:8.22645
1125984576:8.22931
1136474432:8.41319
1094252864:8.73788
1167944000:8.74504
1157454144:8.74951
1146964288:8.75174
```

the code is list as below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

void * func(void * t)
{
        int n = *((int *) t);
        pthread_t pid = pthread_self();
        timeval t1, t2;
        gettimeofday(&t1, 0);
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
                ostringstream os;
                /*
                   char buf[255];
                   int ret = snprintf(buf, 30, "%d", 2000000);
                   buf[ret] = 0;
                 */
        }
        gettimeofday(&t2, 0);
#define DIFF(a, b) ((b.tv_sec - a.tv_sec) + (b.tv_usec - a.tv_usec) / 1000000.0)
        std::cout << pid << ":" << DIFF(t1, t2) << std::endl;
#undef DIFF

        return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int m, n =0;
        m = atoi(argv[1]);
        n = atoi(argv[2]);
        pthread_t tid[m];
        for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
                pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, func, &n);
        for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
                pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked CPU utilization? If both CPUs are 100% busy, your server just can't handle that many threads at once. If not, there may indeed be lock contention involved.

Comment: The synchronization is in the locale classes used by `ostringstream`, but I am unsure how to remove this dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a known problem. [Here](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-300583.html) is a solution for MSVC: linking statically. Perhaps this will also work on linux.

ALternatively (suggested for Sun Studio [here](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa;jsessionid=05BE8F8E7F40A2904A4E58DB02FE10F5?messageID=213206&#213206)), make the streams thread local (instead of process local) to prevent them from being locked by each thread as the other accesses them.

Answer (score 1):

Ostringstream allocates memory on the heap. May be the OS dynamic allocation is protected by a Mutex?