# Convert Double to Hex String?

Tags: c++, floating-point, hex, double

In my project, I read a double variable as hex and load it into a string.

I need to convert that hex string to a double number. I currently use this:

```
double hexstr2double(const std::string& hexstr)
{
    union
    {
        long long i;
        double    d;
    } value;

    value.i = std::stoll(hexstr, nullptr, 16);

    return value.d;
}
```

When I do this:

```
qDebug() << hexstr2double("402540798D23092A");
```

The output is 10.6259. Not exact, but I'm fine with it.

The user then gets to edit that number to anything they want. How can I convert their number back to Hexadecimal representation?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: snprintf with %llx  of the i member of your union?

Comment: ? Sorry, I do not understand your comment. I've only ever coded C++ in Qt

Comment: In what sense is this not exact?

Comment: You will need to address the issue of endianness also.

Comment: @mc360pro I'm increasingly concerned about the endianness problem as David Hefferman pointed out. It certainly all depends on what the purpose of the hexstring is. Your encoding function above and my decoding functions below provides *a* representation of a double, but this representation depends on the endianness of your hardware and it potentially does not match the memory representation (e.g. ordered in memory positions).. As long as you're encoding and decoding on the same machine and without any further processing on the hexstring you're fine.... but if not you will face problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although sstream is a fine answer... there are [concerns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707138/why-ostringstream-could-not-work-well-in-multithreading-environment) and [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/74026/) about the use of streams in multithreaded programs.

similar solution with snprintf:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

double hexstr2double(const std::string& hexstr)
{
    union
    {
        long long i;
        double    d;
    } value;

    value.i = std::stoll(hexstr, nullptr, 16);

    return value.d;
}

std::string double2hexstr(double x) {

    union
    {
        long long i;
        double    d;
    } value;

   value.d = x;

   char buf[17];

   snprintf (buf,sizeof(buf),"%016llx",value.i);
   buf[16]=0; //make sure it is null terminated.

   return std::string(buf);

}

int main(int argc,char **argv) {
 double a=3.141592;
 std::string x=double2hexstr(a);
 double b=hexstr2double(x);

 std::cout << a << std::endl;
 std::cout << x << std::endl;
 std::cout << b << std::endl;
 return 0;
}
```

Edit (alternative version using std::ostringstream)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

double hexstr2double(const std::string& hexstr)
{
    union
    {
        long long i;
        double    d;
    } value;

    value.i = std::stoll(hexstr, nullptr, 16);

    return value.d;
}

std::string double2hexstr(double x) {

    union
    {
        long long i;
        double    d;
    } value;

   value.d = x;

   std::ostringstream buf;
   buf << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(16) << value.i;

   return buf.str();

}

int main(int argc,char **argv) {
 double a=3.141592;
 std::string x=double2hexstr(a);
 double b=hexstr2double(x);

 std::cout << a << std::endl;
 std::cout << x << std::endl;
 std::cout << b << std::endl;
 return 0;
}
```

Note... I'm not saying that std::ostringstream does not work. It has certainly better properties regarding memory safety (as snprintf has better properties over sprintf)... However be aware that (at least in some implementations of STL) in a multithreaded program might lead to excesive locking.

Comment: -1 unless you can back up these mysterious "concerns"

Comment: snprintf identifier not found.

Comment: You've to include `cstdio`. Why are talking about C++, aren't we?

Comment: @mc360pro That last comment was plain rude. Please don't just give up immediately. Surely you have encountered include files before.

Comment: Yes, however I'm developing using Qt and including cstdio didnt solve the issue.

Comment: The fact that some poor developers erroneously think that there string streams might not work in multi-threaded programs is not reason to forsake them.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Sorry? There seems to be a misunderstanding. I was not commenting at all about string streams and their relation to multi-threaded programs.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, edited including links to the concerns. In general, in our experience developing high-performance multithreaded applications (telecom), using ostringstream lead to thread locking. Apparently (as described in one of the links), the streams interface uses something in the locale that needs to be locked, effectively serializing the execution of the stream methods.

Comment: @mc360pro, not sure why is not working. compiled in mine (both using cstdio and stdio.h)  with g++ 4.8.1

Comment: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/15192 Seems like it is not a function of Qt but rather c++11

Comment: Yes, `snprintf` is part of C++11 (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf)  Feel free to use `sprintf`. You will also find that `stoll` is C++11. Of course the question is non-specific about C++ version so a C++11 answer is just fine for me. It's asker's problem that they did not ask for an answer that works on an old standard.

Comment: @mc360pro added version using std::ostringstream.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `union` like this, be careful that is not portable (not conform to C++ standard).

There is a very talk about that : [CppCon 2019: Timur Doumler “Type punning in modern C++”](https://youtu.be/_qzMpk-22cc?t=587)

A conform solution could be:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstring>

double hexstr2double(const std::string& hexstr) {
    uint64_t i = std::stoll(hexstr, nullptr, 16);
    double d;
    std::memcpy(&d,&i,8);
    return d;
}

std::string double2hexstr(double x) {
   uint64_t i;
   std::memcpy(&i,&x,8);

   char buf[17];
   snprintf (buf,sizeof(buf),"%016llx",i);
   buf[16]=0; //make sure it is null terminated.

   return std::string(buf);
}

int main(int argc,char **argv) {
 double a=3.141592;
 std::string x=double2hexstr(a);
 double b=hexstr2double(x);

 std::cout << a << std::endl;
 std::cout << x << std::endl;
 std::cout << b << std::endl;
 return 0;
}
```